# msdeploy deploy.cmd file not parsing parameters properly

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, msdeploy

I build my application with the following msbuild command

```
msbuild ProjectFile.csproj /target:Rebuild;Package /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageLocation=".\obj\Debug\CAREwebNet.zip";PackageAsSingleFile=True
```

This produces a projectFile.deploy.cmd file and I should be able to deploy with the following command

```
ProjectFile.Deploy.cmd /Y /M:MachineName "-replace:match=log4net.config.Debug,replace=log4net.config"
```

but I get the following error

Error: Unrecognized argument '"-replace:match=log4net.config.Debug,replace=log4n
et.config"'. All arguments must begin with "-".
Error count: 1.

Or I try the following ... Not no quotes

```
ProjectFile.Deploy.cmd /Y /M:MachineName -replace:match=log4net.config.Debug,replace=log4net.config
```

And I get the following ...

Error: Unrecognized argument 'log4net.config.Debug'. All arguments must begin with "-".
Error count: 1.

I've tried a number of different options ... and I've tried working through it with a team member. We actually have a very similar project that we do the same thing with and it works perfectly (the one with the quotes).

Below is the deploy.cmd files contents as built by VS.

```
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Copyright 2008 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
@rem This is provided as sample to deploy the package using msdeploy.exe
@rem For information about IIS Web Deploy technology,
@rem please visit http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
@rem Note: This batch file assumes the package and setparametsrs.xml are in the same folder with this file
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@if %_echo%!==! echo off
setlocal
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Please Make sure you have Web Deploy install in your machine. 
@rem Alternatively, you can explicit set the MsDeployPath to the location it is on your machine
@rem set MSDeployPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\"
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem if user does not set MsDeployPath environment variable, we will try to retrieve it from registry.
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if "%MSDeployPath%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy" /s  ^| findstr -i "InstallPath"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "InstallPath" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
if "%%~dpj" == "%%j" ( 
set MSDeployPath=%%j
))))))

if not exist "%MSDeployPath%\msdeploy.exe" (
echo. msdeploy.exe is not found on this machine. Please install Web Deploy before execute the script. 
echo. Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
goto :usage
)

set RootPath=%~dp0
if /I "%_DeploySetParametersFile%" == "" (
set _DeploySetParametersFile=%RootPath%CAREwebNet.SetParameters.xml
)

set _ArgTestDeploy=
set _ArgDestinationType=auto
set _ArgComputerName=
set _ArgUserName=
set _ArgPassword=
set _ArgEncryptPassword=
set _ArgIncludeAcls=False
set _ArgAuthType=
set _ArgtempAgent=
set _ArgLocalIIS=
set _ArgLocalIISVersion=


@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Simple Parse the arguments
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:NextArgument
set _ArgCurrentOriginal=%1
set _ArgCurrent=%~1

if /I "%_ArgCurrent%" == "" goto :GetStarted
if /I "%_ArgCurrent%" == "/T" set _ArgTestDeploy=true&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgCurrent%" == "/Y" set _ArgTestDeploy=false&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgCurrent%" == "/L" set _ArgLocalIIS=true&goto :ArgumentOK

set _ArgFlag=%_ArgCurrent:~0,3%
set _ArgValue=%_ArgCurrent:~3%

if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/M:" set _ArgComputerName=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/U:" set _ArgUserName=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/P:" set _ArgPassword=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/E:" set _ArgEncryptPassword=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/I:" set _ArgIncludeAcls=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/A:" set _ArgAuthType=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK
if /I "%_ArgFlag%" == "/G:" set _ArgtempAgent=%_ArgValue%&goto :ArgumentOK

@rem Any addition flags, pass through to the msdeploy
set _ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags% %_ArgCurrentOriginal%

:ArgumentOK
shift
goto :NextArgument

:GetStarted
if /I "%_ArgTestDeploy%" == "" goto :usage
if /I "%_ArgDestinationType%" == ""  goto :usage

set _Destination=%_ArgDestinationType%
if not "%_ArgComputerName%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,computerName='%_ArgComputerName%'
if not "%_ArgUserName%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,userName='%_ArgUserName%'
if not "%_ArgPassword%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,password='%_ArgPassword%'
if not "%_ArgAuthType%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,authtype='%_ArgAuthType%'
if not "%_ArgEncryptPassword%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,encryptPassword='%_ArgEncryptPassword%'
if not "%_ArgIncludeAcls%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,includeAcls='%_ArgIncludeAcls%'
if not "%_ArgtempAgent%" == "" set _Destination=%_Destination%,tempAgent='%_ArgtempAgent%'

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem add -whatif when -T is specified                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if /I "%_ArgTestDeploy%" NEQ "false" (
set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_MsDeployAdditionalFlags% -whatif
)

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem add flags for IISExpress when -L is specified                      
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if /I "%_ArgLocalIIS%" == "true" (
call :SetIISExpressArguments
)
if /I "%_ArgLocalIIS%" == "true" (
if not exist "%IISExpressPath%%IISExpressManifest%" (
echo. IISExpress is not found on this machine. Please install through Web Platform Installer before execute the script. 
echo. or remove /L flag
echo. Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
goto :usage
)
if not exist "%IISExpressUserProfileDirectory%" (
echo. %IISExpressUserProfileDirectory% is not exists
echo. IISExpress is found on the machine. But the user have run IISExpress at least once.
echo. Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654 for detail
goto :usage
)

set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_MsDeployAdditionalFlags% -appHostConfigDir:%IISExpressUserProfileDirectory% -WebServerDir:"%IISExpressPath%" -webServerManifest:"%IISExpressManifest%"
)

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem pass through the addition msdeploy.exe Flags
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_MsDeployAdditionalFlags% %_ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags%

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem check the existence of the package file
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if not exist "%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip" (
echo "%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip" does not exist. 
echo This batch file relies on this deploy source file^(s^) in the same folder.
goto :usage
)

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Execute msdeploy.exe command line
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
call :CheckParameterFile
echo. Start executing msdeploy.exe
echo -------------------------------------------------------
if  not exist "%_DeploySetParametersFile%" (
echo. "%MSDeployPath%\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension %_MsDeployAdditionalFlags%
      "%MSDeployPath%\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension %_MsDeployAdditionalFlags%
) else (
echo. "%MSDeployPath%\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"%RootPath%CAREwebNet.SetParameters.xml" %_MsDeployAdditionalFlags%
      "%MSDeployPath%\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='%RootPath%CAREwebNet.zip' -dest:%_Destination% -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"%RootPath%CAREwebNet.SetParameters.xml" %_MsDeployAdditionalFlags%
)
goto :eof

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Find and set IISExpress argument.
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:SetIISExpressArguments

if "%IISExpressPath%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress" /s  ^| findstr -i "InstallPath"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "InstallPath" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
if "%%~dpj" == "%%j" ( 
set IISExpressPath=%%j
))))))

if "%IISExpressPath%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IISExpress" /s  ^| findstr -i "InstallPath"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "InstallPath" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
if "%%~dpj" == "%%j" ( 
set IISExpressPath=%%j
))))))

if "%PersonalDocumentFolder%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%i  in (`reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Personal`) do (
set PersonalDocumentFolder=%%j
))

if "%IISExpressManifest%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress" /s  ^| findstr -i "Manifest"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "Manifest" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
set IISExpressManifest=%%j
)))))

if "%IISExpressManifest%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IISExpress" /s  ^| findstr -i "Manifest"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "Manifest" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
set IISExpressManifest=%%j
)))))

set IISExpressUserProfileDirectory="%PersonalDocumentFolder%\IISExpress\config"

goto :eof                      

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem CheckParameterFile -- check if the package's setparamters.xml exists or not
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CheckParameterFile
echo =========================================================
if exist "%_DeploySetParametersFile%" (
echo SetParameters from:
echo "%_DeploySetParametersFile%"
echo You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString
echo or other deploy parameters in the above file.
) else (
echo SetParamterFiles does not exist in package location.
echo Use package embedded defaultValue to deploy.
)
echo -------------------------------------------------------
goto :eof

@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@rem Usage
@rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:usage
echo =========================================================
if not exist "%RootPath%CAREwebNet.deploy-readme.txt" (
echo Usage:%~nx0 [/T^|/Y] [/M:ComputerName] [/U:userName] [/P:password] [/G:tempAgent] [additional msdeploy flags ...]
echo Required flags:
echo /T  Calls msdeploy.exe with the "-whatif" flag, which simulates deployment. 
echo /Y  Calls msdeploy.exe without the "-whatif" flag, which deploys the package to the current machine or destination server 
echo Optional flags:  
echo. By Default, this script deploy to the current machine where this script is invoked which will use current user credential without tempAgent. 
echo.   Only pass these arguments when in advance scenario.
echo /M:  Msdeploy destination name of remote computer or proxy-URL. Default is local.
echo /U:  Msdeploy destination user name. 
echo /P:  Msdeploy destination password.
echo /G:  Msdeploy destination tempAgent. True or False. Default is false.
echo /A:  specifies the type of authentication to be used. The possible values are NTLM and Basic. If the wmsvc provider setting is specified, the default authentication type is Basic
otherwise, the default authentication type is NTLM.
echo /L:  Deploy to Local IISExpress User Instance.  

echo.[additional msdeploy flags]: note: " is required for passing = through command line.
echo  "-skip:objectName=setAcl" "-skip:objectName=dbFullSql"
echo.Alternative environment variable _MsDeployAdditionalFlags is also honored.
echo.
echo. Please make sure MSDeploy is installed in the box http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654
echo.
echo In addition, you can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, 
echo connectionString and other deploy parameters in the following file:
echo "%_DeploySetParametersFile%"
echo.
echo For more information about this batch file, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183544 
) else (
start notepad "%RootPath%CAREwebNet.deploy-readme.txt"
)
echo =========================================================
goto :eof
```

I've also verified the syntax ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx ... but I am still not having any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Microsoft made changes to the way the batch file that is generated parses parameters. This knowledge base article explains it all.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2537134

It basically stems from my visual studio instance having the latest sp1 and not having the new targets file. I know need to update the build server with the new targets file and new visual studio ... maybe ... To make sure that it matches.

Comment: [ProjectName].deploy.cmd file generated was failing when built on our build server too. Replaced Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web with one from here: https://gist.github.com/codeprogression/1065028 which resolved this issue - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue to pass parameters that have equals ('=') symbol.... what I do is set a environment variable with this parameters that automatically MSDeploy will parse then in it execution.

So, in my .proj I have:

```
 <Exec Command="Set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%(PublishPackages.AdditionalMSDeployParameters) %26 $(_Cmd)" />
```

PublishPackages is a variable with this string

```
-allowUntrusted -xml -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*.config -useCheckSum
```

And `%26` is the escape for `&` character.

The `Set` and the call for MSDeploy doesn't work in different `Exec` task call...